# Reloading Data in a Custom Picker

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, protocols, uipickerview

I created a custom Picker with a nice X-ray lens glow effect for the target selection. It is  just made up of two UIScrollViews with the same content offset. When the label goes under the lens it appears to glow. Anyways, I need to dynamically update the data and if it were a normal table view I know I would just use [tableView reloadData]. I have custom delegate methods for assigning labels / rowHeight and some other customizable features. I just need all these delegate methods to be reevaluated after a switch is pressed. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

EDIT:

I thought I was having a brain fart, and for the most part was. I can write my own "reloadData" function in the custom picker class. My only problem is having the picker call the titleForRow delegate method the number of times equal to the number of rows. I know my picker can do it the first time when the view loads. Do I really need to use a FOR loop in my reloadData function or is there something I am missing?

In my reload method I want to call:

[[self delegate] titleForRow:(int) forPicker:self];

Thanks Again!!

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not edit.

Comment: @Moshe - there appears to still be an unanswered question here.

Comment: @TimPost good call. Seems like I missed it. (As did four other upvoters.)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a quick fix.. but sure enough the right way to do this was to use a FOR loop in a custom reload function for my class. The reload code is essentially the same as the initialization code, just removing subviews and repopulating.